# Broken pipe in pipe.stdin.write("stop\n")

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

i have a problem with yandex-tank-jmeter.

My load.ini:

```
[tank]
plugin_web=/usr/lib/yandex-tank/Tank/Plugins/WebOnline.py
[jmeter]
jmx=tw2testplan_0_33.jmx
jmeter_path=/home/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter
args=-r
[graphite]
address=localhost
port=2003
prefix=jmeter
[web]
port=8089
[monitoring]
config=monitoring.xml
```

monitoring.xml:

```
<Monitoring>
<Host address="someip">
<CPU measure="user,system,iowait"/>
<System measure="csw,int"/>
<Memory measure="free,used"/>
<Disk measure="read,write"/>
<Net measure="recv,send"/>
</Host>
</Monitoring>
```

So when test trying to stop i see the next output in console:

```
13:18:13 INFO: Finishing monitoring
13:18:15 WARNING: Killing 15630 with 9
13:18:17 WARNING: Killing 15630 with 9
13:18:21 WARNING: Killing 15630 with 9
```

Process 15630:

```
root@loadtest:~#  ps -ef | grep 15630
root     15630 15593  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 [ssh] <defunct>
```

then I tried to press CTRL+C:

```
13:19:11 INFO: Trying to shutdown gracefully...
13:19:11 INFO: Finishing test...
13:19:11 ERROR: Failed finishing plugin <Aggregator.AggregatorPlugin instance at         0x7f0b7434afc8>: I/O operation on closed file
13:19:11 INFO: Finishing monitoring

3:19:11 WARNING: Problems stopping agent: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/yandex-tank/Tank/MonCollector/collector.py", line 352, in stop
pipe.stdin.write("stop\n")
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

13:19:13 WARNING: Killing 15630 with 9
```

Help me plz with fixing of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as a temporary solution (i don`t know is it ok from python side) was fixed collector.py:

line 358:

```
while tankcore.pid_exists(pipe.pid):
if first_try:
logging.debug("Killing %s with %s", pipe.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
os.killpg(pipe.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
pipe.wait() ----- was added
first_try = False
time.sleep(0.1)
```